# MySQL ALTER TABLE on dev machine is very slow on empty tables

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, alter-table

I'm working on an application that involves some dynamic creation of database schemas.

On my dev machine, MySQL server takes something like **five minutes** to run a dozen `CREATE TABLE` and some hundreds `ALTER TABLE` queries. Tables are completely empty during this process, so indexes should not play a relevant role here. Strange thing is that on the production server (which is really less powerful than my PC!) the process lasts **no more than 10 seconds**. How is that possible?

I'm using InnoDB both on dev and production. MySQL version is 5.6 on dev and 5.5 on production. Queries are run using the same exact PHP script.

I would like to speed up development time by reducing this process' duration, since I need to run lot of tests and debugging on this process.

---

***Edit**: I found a workaround [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399281/mysql-alter-table-on-dev-machine-is-very-slow-on-empty-tables#comment64268176_38399281).*

Comment: When I hear dynamic and SQL in one sentence I am curious. For what do you need that?

Comment: Since you're "dynamically" adding columns, that means you're using **relational** database in a way it's not meant to be used. Since we don't have hardware specs of either computer, I'd conclude that you don't have an SSD whereas the server does. It's also unknown whether there's something else that might be utilizing resources of your dev. computer.

Comment: @juergend Can't say much details, but we are working on a system that deploys DBs that are different for each of our users. We have defined many *templates* (tables and fields) that can be mixed in the process of setting up the DB. I perfectly know that it's not the ideal use case for a RDMS, but we had done lot of analysis, and our app works better on top of a RDB instead of NoSQL, ***after*** it has been set up. This set up process is run only at user sign-up time (not exactly, but you get it).

Comment: @Mjh See reply to juergend... And, yes, it can be. My dev machine is much more powerful in terms of CPU and RAM. The production server is an AWS EC2 less-powerful instance, but in fact could be SSD based.

Comment: There are many ways in which you can use RDBMS to fit your needs. MySQL 5.7 has `json` data type which enables various dynamic setups. CPU / RAM don't play such a huge role in alter/create table as much as HDD does. You can always create a RAM drive if you have sufficient memory and have MySQL store data there (naturally, it's not advised but if you're after speed - that's one solution). There are tools that let you measure what happens, from `strace` to `hdparm` (assuming you're on *nix).

Comment: @Mjh I'm on Linux both on dev and production. I'll try to look at `top` and `iotop`, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is `innodb_file_per_table` the same on both?

Comment: Hundreds of `ALTERs`, or even hundreds of tables, sounds like you might have mis-design the schema.  Please elaborate on why so many.

Comment: @RickJames Already did in comments. Anyway, `innodb_file_per_table` is `ON` on development and `OFF` on production. What can it mean?

Comment: @Mjh The bottleneck was the disk, in fact! `iotop` showed 100% for the MySQL process during the whole time. Thank you, if you write an answer I'll accept it. I managed to make it 10x faster by pre-computing which `ALTER TABLE`s I can execute in the same statement and also by eliminating some of them in the `CREATE TABLE`s, so I have to run less DDL queries overall.

Comment: I just nudged you to the right direction, can you maybe write the answer about how you used `iotop` to determine disk was at fault? It will help people better than half of the answer I can provide :)

Comment: `innodb_file_per_table = ON` means more interaction with the OS - due to the `.ibd` file.  On Windows, especially, this is extra overhead.  I find it best to `CREATE` or `ALTER` the largest tables with `ON`; small tables with `OFF`.